# Weird plot from discontinuous data

Tags: pgfplots

Tex gurus;

I'm trying to plot some data against time, for which I have some missing values. Most of the time, this works well, but for one plot in particular I am getting some very strange results. This data is always 1:1 (ie, there is never more than one data value per time value), and the times are evenly spaced.

Pfgplots is doing a couple of unwanted things:
a) It is plotting more than one data point per time... see the example below; and b) it isn't skipping the missing data like I would expect.

Any ideas?

Latex Snippet:

```
\begin{axis}[c3,name=plot_name,at=(plot1.below south west),anchor=north west,legend cell align=left,ylabel={\small Quantity (-)}line join=round, width=16.85cm,height=4.2cm,ymin=0,ymax=360,xmin=0,xmax=1500]   
\addplot+[smooth,mark=none,color=c3,unbounded coords=jump] table [x=t, y=val, col sep=comma] {file.csv};    
\end{axis}
```

Example of data:

```
t,val
396,54.147
396.1,40.59
396.2,40.59
...
438.4,67.594
438.5,nan
...
894.9,nan
895,60.13
895.1,52.17
```

[image: Dodgy Plot]

Comment: A guess: delete the `smooth` option. Otherwise please provide an MWE.

Comment: Also your data looks like not ordered properly

Comment: Turns out it wasn't anything to do with smoothing or data ordering - An upstream script wasn't correctly inserting 'nan's where it should have been, leaving the field blank instead. Fixed that, and the data is plotting correctly.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem was caused by an error in a script, which therefore generated a badly formatted data file.